# Specify the output on a function node in Node-Red

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, node-red

I want to know how it is possible to specify on which output a function node can return a message (msg).

For example:

```
if( msg.eui == "00:11:22:33:44:55:66:88"){
    output1(msg); //return on the output 1 only
}
if( msg.eui == "00:11:22:33:44:55:66:99"){
    output2(msg); //return on the output 2 only
}
```

What needs to be changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can be done. Node-Red uses an [array of messages to address the different output ports](https://nodered.org/docs/writing-functions#multiple-outputs).

```
if( msg.eui == "00:11:22:33:44:55:66:88"){
    return [msg, null]; //return on the output 1 only
}
if( msg.eui == "00:11:22:33:44:55:66:99"){
    return [null, msg]; //return on the output 2 only
}
```

The output that should not receive the message is set to null, the other to the return message.